# JPA: how to use @ElementCollection annotation?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I need your help to map the relation in Hibernate of two tables using
the @ElementCollection annotation.

The first one is the parent table
Table name: **Parent**
DB Columns

```
KEY1         Char      (first primary key field)
KEY2         Char      (second primary key field)
DESCRIPTION  Char
DEPENDENTID  BigInt
```

The second one is the dependent table
TableName: **Dependent**
DB Columns

```
PARENTID     BigInt    (first primary key field)
CODE         Char      (second primary key field)
FIELD1       Char
FIELD2       Char
```

I need to define the PK for both tables using @EmbeddedId annotation,
so I have created the two classes:

```
@Embeddable
public class ParentPK implements Serializable
{
   @Column(name="K1")
   private String iK1;
   @Column(name="K2")
   private String iK2;
  // I omit the constructor, getter, setter, equals, hashcode method 
}

@Embeddable
public class DependentPK implements Serializable
{
  @Column(name="PARENTID")
  private String iParentId;
  @Column(name="CODE")
  private String iCode;
  // I omit the constructor, getter, setter, equals, hashcode method 
}
```

and then I've created the two beans:
The class for the DEPENDENT table.
Note that in this class I do not want to have any relational annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPENDENT")
public class DependentBean implements Serializable
{
   @EmbeddedId
   private DependentPK iDependentPK;
   @Column(name = "FIELD1")
   private String iField1;
   @Column(name = "FIELD2")
   private String iField2;
   // I omit the constructor, getter, setter methods
}
```

And the class for the PARENT table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class ParentBean implements Serializable
{
   @EmbeddedId
   ParentPK iParentPK;
   @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
   private String iDescription;
   @Column(name = "DEPENDENTID")
   private long iDependentId;
   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="DEPENDENT", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PARENTID",  referencedColumnName="DEPENDENTID")})
   private Set<DependentBean> iDependentBeans = new HashSet<DependentBean>();
   // I omit the constructor, getter, setter methods
}
```

When I try to deploy I got the error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key
>   (FK9619C2A17B05CB2:DEPENDENT
>   [iDependentBeans_PARENTID,iDependentBeans_CODE])) must have same
>   number of columns as the referenced primary key (DEPENDENT
>   [PARENTID,iDependentBeans_PARENTID,iDependentBeans_CODE])

So I'm doing something wrong, but I can not imagine what.
Could anyone wants to help me, please?

Answer (score 8):

@ElementCollection should be used with basic type or embeddable class, not for entity.

The DependentBean is an Entity.

Try to use One To Many Mapping and modify your schema

PARENT schema

```
KEY1         Char      (PK)
KEY2         Char      (PK)
DEPENDENTID  BigInt    (PK)
DESCRIPTION  Char
```

DEPENDENT schema

```
CODE         Char      (PK)
PARENTID     BigInt    (FK)
KEY1         Char      (FK)
KEY2         Char      (FK)
FIELD1       Char
FIELD2       Char
```

One To Many mapping

ParentPK

```
@Embeddable
public class ParentPK {
    @Column(name = "K1")
    private String iK1;
    @Column(name = "K2")
    private String iK2;
    @Column(name = "DEPENDENTID")
    private long iDependentId;
}
```

ParentBean

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class ParentBean {
    @EmbeddedId
    ParentPK iParentPK;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    List<DependentBean> iDependentBeans;
}
```

DependentBean

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPENDENT")
public class DependentBean {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String iCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({ 
      @JoinColumn(name = "PARENTID", referencedColumnName = "iDependentId"),  
      @JoinColumn(name = "K1", referencedColumnName = "iK1"),
      @JoinColumn(name = "K2", referencedColumnName = "iK2") })
    ParentBean parent;
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer.
But I've see that using onetomany annotation Hibernate make a join when is accessed the parent table.
I need to access the dependent table only when its attribute is accessed. So, what's the way to do this?

Comment: I think you use @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER), this surely will make a join as you say. Try to use @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) and make sure that you access the attribute before closing session. Otherwise, you will get a LazyInitializationException.

Comment: Hi again, but is possible to define a OneToMany between my two tables **Parent** and **Dependent**?
As you see **Parent** table has the field 'DEPENDENTID' that might be linked to 'PARENTID' field of **Dependent** table.
**Dependent** table has another primary key field: 'CODE'.
The two tables has its own primary keys described using an embeddable class.
So, in your opinion, is possible to use the @OneToMany annotation in this scenario?
I've tried in several ways without success and I've tried a lot of search without find nothing.
Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Hi @user2711522, your case is not a one to many mapping. The only possible solution is Parent table's composite key (ID, DEPENDENTID)  to be the composite FK of Dependent table.

Comment: Hi @study, thanks for your answer.
if I have understand well: I need to change my Dependent table structure to put the Parent table primary key and then have a foreign key in my Dependent table using those fields to refer to the Parent table. This becomes a ManyToOne between the Dependent table and the Parent table and the ManyToOne relation will be defined in the Dependent pojo. Is this correct? But if so, I not have in my parent pojo the collection of Dependent pojos. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: Hi @study,
following your first post I got this error during JBoss deploy:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: iDependentId in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(PARENT) and its related supertables and secondary tables.
I'm thinking is not possible to map in hibernate my tables structure as is.